# Replace text in form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, text, field, replace

I have a form that has several fields.  The first field is called subject.  What I want to do is disable the ability for the user to type in the field, but it still show, and the text they enter into three other fields show up with spaces between the variables in the first field.  Example: In this scenario: "Second_Field: John" "Third_Field: Doe" "Forth_Field: New part" then on first field, subject, it will show:  John Doe New Part

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Agreed. You need to show some code that you tried that didn't work, and your explanation of what you tried to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="subject" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" id="field1">
<input type="text" id="field2">
<input type="text" id="field3">

// JavaScript
var fields = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    fields.push(document.getElementById("field" + i).value);
}
document.getElementById("subject").value = fields.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function UpdateText()
{
  document.getElementById("subject").value =document.getElementById("Field1").value + " " +   document.getElementById("Field2").value + " " + document.getElementById("Field3").value;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="subject" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="text" id="Field1" onchange="UpdateText()";/>
<input type="text" id="Field2" onchange="UpdateText()";/>
<input type="text" id="Field3" onchange="UpdateText()";/>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form>
<p><input id="subject" name="subject" disabled size="60"></p>
<p><input id="Second_Field" class="part">
   <input id="Third_Field" class="part">
   <input id="Fourth_Field" class="part"></p>
</form>
```

​

JavaScript:

```
var updateSubject = function() {
  var outArray = [];
  for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
      if (parts[i].value !== '' ) {
        outArray.push(parts[i].value);
      }
  }
  document.getElementById('subject').value = outArray.join(' ');
};
var parts = document.getElementsByClassName('part');
for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
  parts[i].onkeydown = updateSubject;
}
```

​